# Configuring data source using secured ports

Tags: tomcat, apache-tomee

We are running an application on TomEE v1.7. I've configured datasource connection using non-secured ports on context.xml and it works fine. Now, we have a need to change them to secured ports. I'm having trouble finding a good way of doing that!! Has anyone in this forum done such configuration? Please share steps or any information that can help me with this configurations.

Thanks, 
Krishna.

Answer (score 0):

So I was finally able to figure the steps out :D

DB2 is the database the we were using so i looked up for DB2 driver options and ran into this below page:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052075.html

of which I took 3 parts:

1. sslConnection
2. sslTrustStoreLocation
3. sslTrustStorePassword

Placed the truststore in a location

and formed the jdbc url like below:

"jdbc:db2://hostname/IP of DB:Secured_port/db_schema_name;sslConnection=true;sslTrustStoreLocation=locatio_of_truststore;sslTrustStorePassword=truststore_pwd;"

If more option are needed get the correct parameter from the ibm doc above and add them to url by separating each parameter with a ";'